# big IF function not working in PHP?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Dears,
I am surprised why the PHP 'IF ELSE' function is not working properly. I guess it's a bit long but I made Algorithm for it and logically it would work perfectly. Can anyone have any clue why the function not working properly . please ..

```
  <?php 
           //entry Marks
  $tc=80;$tf=33;$pc=null;$pf=50;

  if($tc!=NULL && $tf!=NULL && $pc!=NULL && $pf!=NULL){
    echo $tc." ".$tf." ".$pc." ".$pf;
  }else{
      if($tc!=NULL){
        if($tf!=NULL && $pc!=NULL && $pf!=NULL){
          echo "tf.pc.pf";
        }else{
          if($tf!=NULL){
            if($pc!=NULL && $pf!=NULL){
              echo "tf.pc.pf";
            }else{
              if($pc!=NULL){
                if($pf!=NULL){
                  echo "tf.pc.pf";
                }else{
                  echo "tf.pc";
                }
              }else{
                if($pf!=NULL){
                  echo "tf.pf";
                }else{
                  echo "tf";
                }

              }
            }
          }else{
            if($pc!==NULL && $pf!=NULL){
              echo "pc.pf";
            }else{
              if($pc!=NULL){
                if($pf!=NULL){
                  echo "pc.pf";
                }else{
                  echo "pc";
                }
              }else{
                if($pf!=NULL){
                  echo "pf";
                }else{
                  echo "null";
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }else{   //2nd part
          if($tf!=NULL && $pc!=NULL && $pf!=NULL){
            echo "tf.pc.pf";
          }else{
            if($tf!=NULL){
              if($pc!=NULL && $pf!=NULL){
                echo "tf.pc.pf";
              }else{
                if($pc!=NULL){
                  if($pf!=NULL){
                    echo "tf.pc.pf";
                  }else{
                    echo "tf.pc";
                  }
                }else{
                  echo "tf";
                }
              }
            }else{
              if($pc!=NULL && $pf!=NULL){
                echo "pc.pf";
              }else{
                if($pc!=NULL){
                  if($pf!=NULL){
                    echo "pc.pf";
                  }else{
                    echo "pc";
                  }
                }else{
                  if($pf!=NULL){
                    echo "pf";
                  }else{
                    echo "null";
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Wow, this is hard to follow. This should probably be inside a class, where you can break this up into readable chunks inside methods

Comment: this is hell of `if-else`. Break into chunks and try to correct them. No-one even  interested to look to  whole code

Comment: How is the code not working? what is it doing?

Comment: sir, its code for inserting marks into TABLE, sometimes TABLE has TC,TF,PC,PF all column , sometimes IT has only PC, PF column. my target is recognize it which COLUMN is NULL then put the DATA as it is. @noliver

Comment: You need to look at the statements as some of them will never run. Am I correct in assuming if the values are NULL you want to put the text "tf.pf" (example if $tf & $pt are NULL)? @Mdimran

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really difficult to follow, this code sample below shows a simplified version which appends to a string the values or text depending on if the variable is NULL or not. You can change what the if-else statements add to the result string easily. At the end I remove the "." at the end of the final string.

```
$result = "";
if($tc == NULL){
    $result .= "tc.";
}else{
    $result .= $tc.".";
}
if($tf == NULL){
    $result .= "tf.";
}else{
    $result .= $tf.".";
}
if($pc == NULL){
    $result .= "pc.";
}else{
    $result .= $pc.".";
}
if($pf == NULL){
    $result .= "pf.";
}else{
    $result .= $pf.".";
}
$output = rtrim($result, '.');
echo $output;
```

I will update my answer when its a bit clearer what output you are after

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the answer of why your large if-statement do not work. But I do have a suggestion of making a PHP function to handle your specific need:

```
function check($tc=null,$tf=null,$pc=null,$pf=null){

    $r = array();

    if($tc != null){ $r[] = 'tc'; }
    if($tf != null){ $r[] = 'tf'; }
    if($pc != null){ $r[] = 'pc'; }
    if($pf != null){ $r[] = 'pf'; }

    if(empty($r)){ 
        return 'null';
    } else {
        return implode('.', $r);// MAKE STRING OF ARRAY
    }
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
$tc=80;$tf=33;$pc=null;$pf=50;

echo check($tc, $tf, $pc, $pf);
```

Try it out: https://eval.in/735202

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answer, your code is much longer than needed. This length makes it hard to follow. You could use a foreach loop to go through all your columns (which will make adding columns much easier).

Assuming I understand what you are looking for, you could use something like:

```
  $tc=80;$tf=33;$pc=null;$pf=50;

  $columns = array('tc'=>$tc,'tf'=>$tf,'pc'=>$pc,'pf'=>$pf);
  $i = 0;

  $output = "";

  foreach ($columns as $key=> $column) {
      if (!$column == null) {
        $output .= $key.".";
      }
  }

  // strip last period:
  $output = rtrim($output, '.');

  echo $output;
```

Link to php sandbox for [demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/313b5dd87fccdb3eda3ed24f9c5bb216e4223794).